# Mahout transpose matrix

Tags: hadoop, mahout, transpose

I'm new in Mahout.
I'm trying to transpose a matrix with Mahout tranpose command line.

Every line in my data source file is looking like:  `1;456;789;012;....   .` The key is the first element in each line (in this example it is "1"). Every line is a vector of the matrix.

I tried changing the separator with "," or space " ", but I doesn't work.

To transpose the matrix, I started with transforming my hdfs data file in a sequence file using this command:

```
mahout seqdirectory -c utf-8 -i /test/myfile -p /test/myfile_seq
```

Then I tried to convert my sequence file into vectors using this command:

```
mahout seq2sparse -i /test/myfile_seq/chunk-0 -o /test/myfile_vector
```

Then to tranpose I used this command:

```
sudo -u hdfs mahout transpose --input  /test/myfile_vector//tfidf-vectors/part-r-00000 --numRows 5 --numCols 24
```

I have several question:

> ```
> - What is the separator to use in the data file source
> - What should be the output of the "mahout seqdirectory" command?
> - Did I need to convert my sequence file to vectors to transpose?
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please post Mahout related questions to Mahout user@ mailing list, to get more quick and definitive answers from Mahout committers.

Mahout's TransposeJob expects a matrix as input and wouldn't work on individual vectors as u have it.
It doesn't matter what you are input format is. You could just have had a CSV file and parsed each line.

Here's the sequence of steps for what u r trying to accomplish:

1. Convert the input CSV file into Named Vectors where the VectorId would be the Key in your case. Look at the code for Mahout's CSVIterator and tweak it to handle Named Vectors and parse each line from your input.
2. Run Mahout's RowIdJob on the NamedVectors to create a Matrix of all the vectors. Each row of the matrix would be a line from your input. The outputs from RowIDJob are - matrix and docIndex.

   matrix - m*n matrix of all concatenated matrix of all vectors
   docIndex - mapping of documentId to documentName (in ur case it would be mapping a documentId to ur key)
3. Feed the matrix output from previous step as input to TransposeJob. You need to specify the number of Rows and columns to CLI.

Please post to Mahout user@ if you have any more questions.